# Custom Typescript NPM Package Won't Generate Types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I've got an npm package that I've built that's Typescript and for some reason when building, it's not generating type definition files and when I try to run it I get the classic `Could not find a declaration file for module...`

I've tried adding `types` and `typings` to package.json with no luck.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@org/mypackage",
  "version": "0.0.7",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/sample/sample.git"
  },
  "author": "Ken M",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/sample/sample/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/sample/sample#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.13",
    "@types/node": "12.0.2",
    "@types/react": "16.8.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "tachyons": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.9.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "prettier": "^1.17.1",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

See tsconfig.json below. Adding `declaration: true` to it did not result in a file getting generated. For what it's worth, the `main: index.js` isn't getting generated either.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: Please post your `tsconfig.json` file, if you have one.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin tsconfig added above.

Comment: When you build with `tsc` is there any build output at all? What is that build output?

Comment: Okay. So it is generating type files but it's generating one per class. I want it to be combined. @ShaunLuttin

Comment: In a situation like this, when your original question has received a working answer, it is appropriate to ask a new question. That helps to limit questions to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer  I appreciate that you are new to StackOverflow and would not be aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Short Answer

Add `declaration` to the `compilerOptions` section of your `tsconfig.json` file.

```
"declaration": true, /* Generates corresponding .d.ts file. */
```

Alternatively, change your `build` script to include `--declaration`.

```
"build": "tsc --declaration"
```

Both options will cause `npm run build` to generate declaration files.

Then update your `package.json` file by adding a `types` property that points to the main declaration file. In the following example, I have assumed that your main declaration file is at `./index.d.ts`.

```
"main": "index.js",
"types": "index.d.ts",
```

#### Additional Details

The opening section of [the Publishing docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) have more detail about the answer.

There are also additional [compiler options here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). Here are three that might be useful in your situation:

- `declarationDir` Output directory for generated declaration files.
- `declarationMap` Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding `.d.ts` file.
- `emitDeclarationOnly` Only emit `.d.ts` declaration files.

The last option in the list is handy when you are already using `babel` to transform files from TypeScript to JavaScript and only want to use TypeScript to generate declaration files and to perform type checking.

Comment: I added the `tsconfig` above to show more about my setup. Making the changes suggested above did not result in declaration generation.